# Exclude parts from compilation - still syntax-check

Tags: c++, macros

We have a pretty large project here in C++/.NET/Visual Studio, for performance testing we incuded some code that makes it possible to evaluate the execution time between certain points.

```
PERFORMANCE_TEST BeginMeasureTime("execute someCode")
someCode
PERFORMANCE_TEST EndMeasureTime("execute someCode")
```

Usually while developing the PERFORMANCE_TEST macro would be set to `//` so the evaluation code is switched off. So if code / interfaces etc. change and the code after the `PERFORMANCE_TEST` macro becomes invalid, the developer will not notice that.

Is there any smarter way to have the performance evaluation code only built in a special version of the project but still make sure that it stays consistent? How would you normally do something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by stays consistent ? what you are doing right now removes the code when you change the PERFORMANCE_TEST what do you wish to achieve ?

Comment: right, the code is removed and therefore also not syntax-checked. I want the code to be compiled (or at least syntax-checked) but not executed. Accepted answer pretty is a pretty good solution

Comment: It can also depend on the checker as CPPCheck can be configured to scan certain #define as static analysis is done before pre-processing checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way would be to change

```
PERFORMANCE_TEST xxx
```

to

```
PERFORMANCE_TEST(xxx)
```

Then instead of

```
#if PERFORMANCE_TEST_ENABLED
#define PERFORMANCE_TEST
#else
#define PERFORMANCE_TEST //
#endif
```

you could have

```
#if PERFORMANCE_TEST_ENABLED
#define PERFORMANCE_TEST(x) {x;}
#else
#define PERFORMANCE_TEST(x) if(0) { x; }
#endif
```

An optimizing compiler should generate no code for the second version if performance tests are disabled (or at the very least it'll not branch on the `if`), but it'll still be part of the compilation.

Alternatively, if build times aren't a *huge* concern you could simply always build both versions into separate directories.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I did something like this the following should be what you want. If the MACRO is defined then the function is included, else it the function is a noop and compiled out the code.

```
 #ifdef MACRO

 #define MACRO_NAME(arg1, arg2, ...) [code to expand to]

 #else

 #define MACRO_NAME(arg1, arg2, ...) noop

 #endif
```

Update:
Ok so I slightly got the question a bit incorrect.

Most static analysis tools can be configured to scan certain #defines
CPPCheck for example can be given the following arguments.

```
-D<ID>               Define preprocessor symbol. Unless --max-configs or
                     --force is used, Cppcheck will only check the given
                     configuration when -D is used.
                     Example: '-DDEBUG=1 -D__cplusplus'.
```

So you can then scan the code twice, thus achieving your goal.
I would say this is the best of both before you can add more scans if you add more #define

Or you can use some of the following to scan more configurations.

```
-f, --force          Force checking of all configurations in files. If used
                     together with '--max-configs=', the last option is the
                     one that is effective.
```

and

```
--max-configs=<limit>
                     Maximum number of configurations to check in a file
                     before skipping it. Default is '12'. If used together
                     with '--force', the last option is the one that is
                     effective.
```

We used this type of operation at a previous company, we build code for WIN32, Pocket PC and WM5 and WM6 all from the same code base but had static checking on all build configurations. But the end result was the removal of non redundant code in all builds.

Comment: That is exactly what they're doing right now. The issue is that they not only want a noop, they want a noop that only compiles inside the macro compiles.

Comment: @Cubic Thanks for that, I have updated my answer to explain how to achieve a scan of both configurations.